# No response from UART

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, uart

I'm able to receive with the following code, but unfortunately, nothing is sent back. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <pic18f25k80.h>
#include "config.h"
#include <usart.h>

int i = 0;
unsigned char MessageBuffer[200];

void main() {
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b110;    // 8MHz
    TRISB6 = 0;                 // TX set as output
    TRISB7 = 0;                 // RX set as output

    // Clear TX interrupt
    // Set RX interrupt
    // 8-bit Asynch. mode
    // BRGH = 1 = high baud mode
    // 51 = ((8MHz/baud)/16)-1   with baud = 9600

    Open2USART(USART_TX_INT_OFF & USART_RX_INT_ON & USART_ASYNCH_MODE
            & USART_EIGHT_BIT & USART_BRGH_HIGH, 51 );

    RC2IF = 0;                  // reset RX2 flag
    RC2IP = 0;                  // not high priority
    RC2IE = 1;                  // Eneble RX2 interrupt
    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;        // enable peripheral interrupts
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;         // enable interrupts
    RCSTA2bits.SPEN = 1;        // enable USART

    while(1){
    }
}

void interrupt ISR () {
    if(PIR3bits.RC2IF == 1) {
        if(i<200) {             // buffer size
            MessageBuffer[i] = Read2USART();        // read byte from RX reg
            if (MessageBuffer[i] == 0x0D) {           // check for return key
                puts2USART(MessageBuffer);
                for(;i>0;i--)
                    MessageBuffer[i] = 0x00;        // clear array
                i=0;
                return;
            }
            i++;
            RC2IF = 0;                              // clear RX flag
        } else {
            puts2USART(MessageBuffer);
            for(;i>0;i--)
                MessageBuffer[i] = 0x00;            // clear array
            i = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm transmitting the 0x41 hex code, I checked with the scope and see that is is being received. And according to the code I have, an echo of the received data should be sent back. When I check the TX pin, nothing is happening.

Comment: Tried `printf()`'s to see which parts of your code get run?

Comment: You probably want to set the RX pin as input

Comment: It doesn't matter if i set RX pin as input or not, it's not declared by the port peripheral, but by UART itself.

It looks like 'puts2USART' is not the right function for data transmittion. I've tried 'TXREG2 = RCREG2;'. So everything that is received go to the Transmit register, and it worked. But still searching for a function that would do something like 'send: "text"'

Comment: You say "I'm transmitting the 0x41 hex code". Are you sending 0x0D after the 0x41? The received data will not be echoed back until 0x0D is received.

Answer (score 0):

Add USART_CONT_RX to Open2USART to enable continuous receive.

Also, it's a good idea to do the minimum necessary in the interrupt service routine. Consider something like:

```
void interrupt ISR () {
  char data;

  if(PIR3bits.RC2IF == 1) {
    data = Read2USART();        // always read byte from RX reg (clears RC2IF)
    if(i<200) {                 // buffer size
      MessageBuffer[i] = data;  // read byte from RX reg
      i++;
    }
    else{
      // flag buffer full error
    }
  }
}
```

and doing the rest of what you are doing in the while(1) loop.